# A religion where everyone is considered a priest

Tags: society, religion, social-norms

I have imagined a universalising polytheistic religion of around 5 million adherents.

The pantheon is composed of 120 deities.

A strange thing about this religion is that everyone is considered a priest.

So, I wonder how would rituals be done.

Note: everyone can marry and reproduce in this religion.

Comment: *"A strange thing about this religion is that everyone is considered a priest":* Yes, I have always considered Lutherans, Calvinists, Baptists, Methodists and so on to be very strange indeed; and Jews and Muslims, of course. (Because saying that "everybody is a priest" is equivalent to saying that "there are no priests".) On the other hand, what major religions do you know where they *have* a distinction between priests and laity, except the Catholic, Orthodox and Anglican Christians?

Comment: @AlexP   Also Episcopalians but that is just the American branch of the Anglican Church. So, you are basically right. We just consider ourselves separate because of the whole situation over bishops after the Revolutionary War. We got them in the end from Scotland(the entire reason why the Scottish flag is on our crest).

Comment: "How would rituals be done?" is asking us to write your story.  "How would the worldwide growth of the number of adherence be fast?" is a separate question which is a) asking us to write your story; and b) depends on a vast number of factors not specified, especially as we don't even know in what period or location/s the starting (?) 5 million adherents are, whether they are proselytizing actively, attitude of governments towards them etc.  (That's assuming this is an alternate history Earth, based on the species of sacred organisms specified.)

Comment: When everyone is a priest... no one is.

Comment: @Martamo: As far as I knew, the Episcopalian church was part of the Anglican communion. I had no idea that they had separated.

Comment: @AlexP   Well, we are. But being American and all, we like to see ourselves as separate on a local level.

Comment: @AlexP and Mormons... but more to the point. (a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question (VTC:NMF). (b) Inherence is a fairly Catholic concept that will work as you define it. It's not "intrinsic" to the nature of your idea, it's wholly subject to you. This means it's "Too Story-Based." (c)  Various religions and philosophies have grown quickly in a variety of ways - and your system could make use of all of them. From traditional proselyting to modern cult-based mind games - what have your studies in this regard failed to teach you that we need to resolve?

Comment: @AlexP as I am aware, Buddhism and Shinto have priest separated from laity, and while Shinto is localized almost strictly in Japan, Buddhism is worldwide currently.

Comment: @AlexP --- The Anglican "Communion" is too much of a mess right now to tell who is in communion with who and who has separated. Fun fact: a huge swath of Anglicanism recently rejected the leadership of Welby. Perhaps when the dust is settled more sense can be made of the question!

Comment: In [Discordianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discordianism), everyone is not just considered a priest but a pope.

Comment: "I wonder how would rituals be done, how would inherence work, and how would the worldwide growth of the numbers of adherents be fast." That's 3 broad questions. Vote to close as we like one question per question please and thanks.

Comment: @Vesper: There are no priests in Buddhism. Monks, yes, and quite comparable with Christian monks. Not everybody who takes religious orders is a priest. No idea about Shintoism.

Comment: I agree with @SurpriseDog: a religion where every believer is a priest, no-one is a priest. There is no way to distinguish between believer / practitioner / priest. So, why do that?

Comment: I think that "priest" just no longer has meaning. This is a perspective born of a religion where only certain people are allowed to do certain things. If everyone is allowed to baptize and perform marriages and shrive, then priesthood becomes an occupation. There are actually many occupations within priesthood: records keeper, philosopher, politician, and police, to name a few. "Master of Ceremonies" is a real thing, so why not recognize it as such?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Look at Protestantism

As AlexP has alluded to, an important doctrine that Protestant Christians hold to is called the [Priesthood of All Believers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priesthood_of_all_believers)

A priesthood is a selected group that has full access to a god that is not enjoyed by others.

The basic premise of the Priesthood of All Believers is that the Old Testament Jewish priesthood, like most other OT features, were a foreshadowing of Jesus; once Jesus was crucified and resurrected, all his followers became priests as they have the right of full and direct access to God in all respects, with no intermediary priesthood needed. Repent and believe in Jesus? You're a believer, so you're a priest.

A minister or pastor is merely there to facilitate worship / organise other believers; spiritually, they're no different to anyone else.
This is in contrast with Catholicism and Eastern Orthodoxy and to some extent, Anglicanism, which as in many other matters are more like Catholics than other Protestants.

It's an internal eye roll moment for many Protestants when we (I am one) are accused of being some sort of religion for the benefit of powerful  clergy; we've had P.O.A.B as a core doctrine for 500 years, and departure from it is sufficient to be considered fringe and very likely heretical.
But what's 500 years and probably 90% adherence to the principle compared to a headline about a tyrannical and corrupt pastor? Very little, in the secular Anglophone media, as a rule.

The thing that holds Protestants together doctrinally, insofar as we are all together is scripture; rituals/sacraments are minimal and with the exception of Communion and Baptism, are agreed to be unimportant and non mandatory.

Re: growth, despite the current decline of Christianity in the USA and Europe, 30 or 40% of all Sub Saharan Africans have become Christians since 1960; that's hundreds of millions of people. The Reformation and Great Awakenings were little slower. So in a word, yes, fast. There's a huge amount of 'Just do it' missionary efforts of every description.

Comment: My brother answered it first haha. Might be helpful to quote 1 Peter 2:9 as the OP can include a similar holy statement in his world.

Comment: Note: Catholicism and Orthodoxy do in fact teach the priesthood of the baptised.

Comment: @elemtilas I understand (and disagree with) the Catholic doctrine, where the common priesthood needs the actions of the ministerial priesthood (particularly the mass and communion) for full access to God. I don't think you actually disagree with the sentence that mentions the RCC and EO churches, though, right? And outside of discussions of the POAB, I assume you use the normal priest/layman parlance that everyone else does, for convenience. Fair?

Comment: "A priesthood is a selected group that has full access to a god that is not enjoyed by others" does not match the common meaning of the word "priest" and I suspect it does not match Mammifere's definition either.

Comment: @Daron The first definition Google throws up for me was from MW: "Someone who is authorized to perform the sacred rites of a religion especially as a mediatory agent between humans and God". Pretty darned close. And, from reason rather than authority: What good is a priest if they have no special access to God that someone else does not have? Why would the job exist in the first place?

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant I'd agree with "Someone who is authorized to perform the rites of a religion". Even without divine inspiration, the job would exist so it can be done as a job, because other non-priest people are busy doing their other jobs all day and don't have time for priest stuff.

Comment: @Daron Like it or not, that mediator part is there. One can't complain that someone isn't using a normal definition but then dispute the dictionary. In Judaism and Christianity, at the least, the mediator role was spelled out at length (in both OT and NT). Specialisation would not explain why most priesthoods require initiation, etc, and have a monopolistic model. You can't just declare yourself a priest doing the priest work at most temples. You need to be made sacred.

Comment: @Daron Who is Mammifere? I googled the word and kept getting results about milk producing mammals.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant I mean the asker mammifereviolet4694

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant As a native English speaker, all I can tell you I was not involved in writing that particular page of the dictionary.

Comment: This isn't the place to argue about whether the 500 year old Protestant doctrine is right and the 2000 year old Catholic/Orthodox doctrine is wrong. I'm simply pointing out that all Christians share this concept of the universal priesthood. Thus lending support to your answer. Also, you can add us Catholics (and probably Orthodox too!) among the eye rollers when people accuse us religion existing to support or benefit a powerful clergy. Generally those accusations are made from ignorance. (cont)

Comment: (cont) --- I reckon the only thing I would really suggest is focusing on the doctrine of POAB itself. The final paragraph seems a bit extraneous, and the paragraph on Baptism and communion (traditionally and historically major sacraments of the Church) could be used to focus your answer a bit. E.g., even though the Church has had the concept of POAB for millennia, and we all participate in the sacrifice, it's only the ministerial priest who is sanctioned to do the sacrificing bit (eucharist) on the altar.

Comment: @elemtilas At the time I answered, the question was longer and speculated on what rituals would look like and if a religion without a priest/non priest distinction could grow quickly. Re: the Church's stance, it dates from V2, and I won't argue the theology of it, but lets just say in a solidly Catholic publication (I read a couple), when it refers to a priest, it *never* means the common priesthood. And I would bet that in your day to day conversation, when you refer to a priest, you don't say, "a ministerial priest", but just say "priest". Charitably, the practice lags behind the teaching.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant --- I never argued that the unqualified word "priest" is used in common language to apply to everyone. I too am well aware of Catholic usage in apologetics, which is why I made the point to begin with. It's not just a Protestant innovation! And of course, no one goes around saying "the ministerial priest" --- but there are obviously situations where we have to understand the distinction. Why do we have  a (ministerial) priesthood at all if every Catholic/Orthodox faithful is a "priest", for example. Also, when dialoguing with Protestants, it's important to (cont)

Comment: (cont) know why Fr Martin himself chose to devise his own doctrine on POAB, rather than the situation that had existed for the previous 1500 years. It also helps in understanding the practices of all the splinter groups that have been born from his revolution.

Answer (score 5):

**Gods watch over every worshipper of them**

Something like what you requested is depicted in *Dragonlance*, where any worshipper had the right to directly call upwards and receive a blessing or something else, depending on their relation to the god they contact. There was a pantheon of 3x7, so your 120 deities could also be fitting, yet they should be more than imaginary to expand such a religion, especially should your world be industrial age or higher.

About details - there could be literally any chaos, especially if those deities would have some conflicts "in the heavens" by their nature or character, as an example, look at Ancient Greek pantheon. So the religion, if not supported by the divine intervention, would be free-for-all, in or out, and in a modern world it would quickly split by "who is existing and who is not", and dissolve.

In a modern world with no visible gods (or a dominant monotheistic religion with something supporting it for this long) your religion would not be able to actively expand their follower base, and even if it would, a hundred gods call for Occam's razor somewhere, and should it be applied, the religion would fall apart. In a medieval or earlier world people won't be "all priests" because they would lack education to understand what is needed of them as priests, so that religion would at least change somehow, developing priests out of whole set of believers sooner or later.

A *monotheistic* religion with everyone as priest does exist, as explained in the answer by AncientGiantPottedPlant, yet it should be noted that it grew out from Christianity that had priests distinctly separated from the rest of believers, at least for educational reasons, as not everyone *back then* could properly explain what's going on in the Bible or Gospels. Protestantism (Calvinism in particular) was not possible until widespread education as a means to transfer aggregated knowledge to everyone with brains, not to select few to rule the peasantry.

Comment: I'd dispute the history there, personally. The NT appears to very much depict pretty uneducated people becoming leaders overnight and a very participatory model of church gathering, as well as a repeated theme of God's wisdom in the lowly beating the wisdom of the wise and educated. Still upvoted.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant well NT does just that, but by God's grace and not by other means. Anyway, priests had to be developed as local churces grew and apostles ran out of time to control the mundane part of church's operation (cf Acts 6). Eventually a lower layer of priests formed (not enough data on how), deacons, still they are counted as priests. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

When everyone is a priest, then nobody is a priest.

Perhaps there is some theological theory that says that contrary to other religions every adherent of the religion is also technically a priest. [Which is actually a real-world concept of Protestant Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priesthood_of_all_believers). But in everyday practice, that would be rather meaningless. A leader who doesn't lead anyone isn't a leader.

So either you have a caste of religious leaders *above* priests who provide religious guidance to the regular adherents of the religion and perform certain rituals (call them "bishops" or "high priests" if you want), or the whole faith is an unorganized religion with no hierarchy at all and everyone worships the gods and performs the rituals on their own.

Comment: Or they act as priest for their family. Or they trade off doing priest work. Or each person is a priest of a different part of the community religion and have different roles and different things to do in the community festivals.

Answer (score 3):

> how would rituals be done

-- what are they asking of their gods? The polytheistic religions tend to have a very businesslike approach to rituals: you give god(s) something they want, in return for them giving you something you want.

(Which also means that everybody being a priest isn't a strange thing at all. Everybody *is* a priest in this system; it's just that some gods have a price beyond any individual's means, so you can only strike a deal with them if you pool your resources and send out a representative to negotiate on your behalf.)

Answer (score 2):

## Just Because Everyone *Can* Doesn't Mean Everyone *Does*

There will always be people who are more interested in some subject and those who are less interested. How these people interact with the subject will similarly vary.

For example, in the real world *everyone* is an musician. There is no special group who are the only ones allowed to write or perform or comission music. Despite this, people still go out their way to find a good DJ for their wedding.

Some people are skilled and devote their lives to their practice. Some of these people become incredibly influential whilst others wallow in obscurity.

Other people are not practioners themselves but spend large amounts of resources to experience excellence. Their tastes and preferences vary wildly, even across an individuals lifetime.

Some take a critical view and try to influence what people produce and experience, whether through writing  or tutoring.

Some people don't care and just go with whatever everyone else is doing.

Is a record label executive all that different to a cardinal in deciding what the masses receive? Is a local holy man filling a similar role to a village band? People genuinely believe good music makes life better and people believe good religious practice will too. Exactly how they try to achieve this depends on who you're talking to.